# Issue with looping a function using a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm having some issues with a for loop. When I run the code, the function seems to run once, as a random list is displayed, but not the expected number that is specified.

Can anyone help me out?

```js
function List(max,min,numLists,numItems){
    this.max = max,
    this.min = min,
    this.numLists = numLists,
    this.numItems = numItems,
    this.generateList = function (){
       
        var fullArray = [];
        var completeArray = [];
        var numItems = this.numItems
        
        
        //create an array of integers between min and max values
        for ( i = this.min ; i<(this.max+1) ; i++) {
            fullArray.push(i);
            }
            
        //select a random value from array of integers and add to new array    
        for ( j = 0 ; j<numItems ; j++) { 
            var randomItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * (fullArray.length));
            completeArray.push(fullArray[randomItem]);
            }
            
        //write new random list
        document.write(completeArray);
        
        }

    this.generateMultipleLists = function() {

     var numLists = this.numLists;

     //loop list creation to create multiple list arrays
     for ( i=0 ; i<numLists ; i++ ){
       this.generateList();
     }
    } 
}   
var newList = new List ( 100 , 12 , 7,15);
newList.generateMultipleLists();
```

Comment: Need to know expected output, and why your output from the program is wrong if we are to help you

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to this it's all sorted now though

Answer (score 0):

Don't create global variables 
In the function generateMultipleLists use `var i` in for loop instead of just `i`.

Comment: Correct, but you should explain why.

Comment: You are creating global variables in for loop

Comment: Use local variables for iterating in loops

Comment: Thanks, I've done some reading up on this now and I think I understand, thanks for the help